Cookie not store to Vue app from Laravel app
I wanna ask something about how to get the cookie from backend Laravel app (in this moment I already set the token and ready store to my Vue app) to frontend Vue app, so I have been tried every single way to solve, start from must do settings on cors.php on my Laravel app until adding credentials: include in my Vue App, but the result still nothing my cookie value is not store to my Vue app browser, and I wanna know why is happen, I will send my code in bellow to make clear my problem.
Laravel App:
AuthController.php
public function login(Request $request): JsonResponse {
    try {
        // describe all the variables
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

        // call a validator rules
        $validatorRules = $this->loginValidatorRules();

        // make a validation
        $validator = Validator::make($credentials, $validatorRules['rules'], $validatorRules['messages']);

        // validate the validation rules
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            // return to validation exception
            throw new ValidationException($validator, 422);
        }

        // login step
        $user = User::where('email', $credentials['email'])->first();

        // check if the user is not registered
        if (empty($user)) {
            throw new Exception('akun belum terdaftar, silahkan daftar terlebih dahulu.', 404);
        }

        // compare the text password (hashed) with the database password
        $isPassword = Hash::check($credentials['password'], $user->password);

        // check the password
        if (!$isPassword) {
            throw new Exception('password yang dimasukkan salah, silahkan coba lagi.', 401);
        }

        // attempt the token auth
        $token = Auth::guard('api')->attempt($credentials);

        // check the token
        if (!$token) {
            throw new Exception('terjadi kesalahan pada saat autentikasi, silahkan hubungi admin (kode error: token).', 401);
        }

        // create a refresh token
        $plainRefreshToken = Str::random(60);
        
        // hash the plain refresh token
        $hashedRefreshToken = hash('sha256', $plainRefreshToken);

        // store the hashed refresh token to user database
        User::where('id_user', $user->id_user)->update(['refresh_token' => $hashedRefreshToken]);

        // store the access token to cookie
        $accessTokenCookie = cookie('access_token', $token, Auth::factory()->getTTL(), null, null, true, true, false, 'None');

        // store the plain refresh token to cookie
        $plainRefreshTokenCookie = cookie('refresh_token', $plainRefreshToken, 2880, null, null, true, true, false, 'None');

        // create payload data
        $payload = [
            'data' => [
                'session' => $this->respondWithToken($token, $plainRefreshToken),
                'user' => [
                    'id_user' => $user->id_user,
                    'role' => $user->getRoleNames(),
                    'name' => $user->name,
                    'email' => $user->email,
                    'email_verified_at' => $user->email_verified_at,
                ],
            ]
        ];

        // return success response
        return ResponseJson::responseJson('success', 'Login berhasil', 200, 'Login telah berhasil', $payload)
            ->cookie($accessTokenCookie)
            ->cookie($plainRefreshTokenCookie);
    } catch (ValidationException $exception) {
        // return error validation message
        return ResponseJson::responseJson('error', 'Validasi gagal', $exception->response, $exception->errors());
    } catch (Exception $exception) {
        dd($exception);
        // return error credentials for login message
        return ResponseJson::responseJson('error', 'Login gagal', $exception->getCode(), $exception->getMessage());
    }
}

cors.php
<?php

return [

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) Configuration
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may configure your settings for cross-origin resource sharing
| or "CORS". This determines what cross-origin operations may execute
| in web browsers. You are free to adjust these settings as needed.
|
| To learn more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS
|
*/

'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],

'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

'allowed_origins' => ['*'], // ex: http://11.18.0.7:5173/

'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

'exposed_headers' => [],

'max_age' => 0,

'supports_credentials' => true,

];

Vue App:
fetch.js (fetch store)
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';
import { ref } from 'vue';

export const useFetchStore = defineStore('fetch', () => {
  const initUrl = ref('');
  const initMethod = ref('');
  const initToken = ref('');
  const initFormData = ref({});

  function setup({ url, method, token = null, formData = null }) {
    initUrl.value = url;
    initMethod.value = method;
    initToken.value = token;
    initFormData.value = formData;
  }

  async function handleRequest() {
    const setupFetch = {
      method: initMethod.value,
      mode: 'cors',
      credentials: 'include',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    };

    // for the request only require the token
    if (initToken.value !== null) {
      setupFetch.headers = {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${initToken.value}`,
        ...setupFetch.headers,
      };
    }

    // for method POST or PUT
    if (initMethod.value === 'POST' || initMethod.value === 'PUT') {
      setupFetch.body = JSON.stringify(initFormData.value);
    }

    const setupSavOrUpdateFetch = {
      cache: 'no-cache',
      credentials: 'same-origin',
    };

    const finalSetupFetch = {
      ...setupFetch,
      ...(initMethod.value === 'POST' || initMethod.value === 'PUT'
        ? setupSavOrUpdateFetch
        : {}),
    };

    const fetchTimeout = new Promise((_, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        const timeoutError = {
          status: 'error',
          title: 'Request timeout',
          detail: {
            code: 408,
            messages:
              'terlalu lama pada saat memproses permintaan, waktu habis, silahkan hubungi admin atau coba lagi (kode error: timeout).',
          },
        };

        const textTimeoutError = JSON.stringify(timeoutError);

        reject(new Error(textTimeoutError));
      }, 15000);
    });

    const response = await Promise.race([
      fetch(initUrl.value, finalSetupFetch),
      fetchTimeout,
    ]);

    if (!response.ok) {
      if (response.status === 500) {
        const customError = {
          status: 'error',
          title: 'Server internal error',
          detail: {
            code: response.status,
            messages:
              'terjadi kesalahan pada server, silahkan hubungi admin (kode error: server).',
          },
        };

        const textError = JSON.stringify(customError);

        throw new Error(textError);
      }

      if (response.status !== 500) {
        const textError = await response.text();

        throw new Error(textError);
      }
    }

    return await response.json();
  }

  return { initUrl, initMethod, initFormData, setup, handleRequest };
});

Result:

in image above when I see the request result and move to headers tab that tokens is already sent, but when I see in the tab application nothing cookie showed.

I hope my explanation in above it's clear so that everyone can understand my problem, thank you before

I think you are looking for spa authentication
https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/sanctum#spa-authentication
If you are not creating single page appication then you should be use Bearer token. Even above code requiring for the same. For generating token, you can use  packages like sanctum or passport.

Thank you for answering this, so I must using sanctum or passport to built SPA? without that I cannot built the SPA auth? or there's other way to achieve this?

This may help if you switch to SPA - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76952349/how-to-save-state-logged-in-on-restart-page-on-vuejs/76952588#76952588
